# How to start and kill tcpdump within a script?

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, scripts, apache2

Why can't I interrupt (i.e. `kill -2`, **not** `kill -9`) `tcpdump` as shown in this script?  The script runs, but `tcpdump` does not terminate and continues to run at the command line, even after printing some of its exit output.

(Note: this script requires `sudo` due to `tcpdump` and `kill`).

```
#!/bin/bash  

#start a process in the background (it happens to be a TCP HTTP sniffer on  the loopback interface, for my apache server):   

tcpdump -i lo -w dump.pcap 'port 80' &  

#.....other commands that send packets to tcpdump.....

#now interrupt the process.  get its PID:  
pid=$(ps -e | pgrep tcpdump)  
echo $pid  

#interrupt it:  
kill -2 $pid
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Does the script work up until the kill part or does the initial tcpdump command take over and prevent anything after from running?

Comment: the script works fine up until the kill part; `echo $pid` works..

Comment: actually, something very strange happens: after `echo` prints the PID, part of `tcpdump`'s normal output (i.e. the output you'd see when it is terminated) is successfully printed to the terminal, and then a new prompt is issued that contains `tcpdump`'s starting message..

Comment: just found out that `kill -9 $pid` works, considering rephrasing the question, as I would like to interrupt and not kill the process..

Comment: For what it's worth, `pid=$(ps -e | pgrep tcpdump); kill -2 $pid` can be condensed to `pkill -2 tcpdump`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found part of the answer [on this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244761/libpcap-error-truncated-dump-file-bogus-savefile-header).

To summarize, `tcpdump` was buffering its output before writing to the output file, and this caused issues when the script attempted to interrupt it.  Adding the `-U` ("flush") option to `tcpdump` fixes this.

Also necessary were a `sleep` command immediately after issuing `tcpdump` to allow it to initialize, and also before killing it, to allow it to write to the file:

```
#!/bin/bash  

#start a process in the background (it happens to be a TCP HTTP sniffer on  the loopback interface, for my apache server):   

tcpdump -U -i lo -w dump.pcap 'port 80' &   
sleep 5

#.....other commands that send packets to tcpdump.....

#now interrupt the process.  get its PID:  
pid=$(ps -e | pgrep tcpdump)  
echo $pid  

#interrupt it:  
sleep 5
kill -2 $pid
```

For reference, from `man tcpdump`, under the `-U` option:

> ```
> If  the -w option is specified, make the saved raw packet output 
> ``packet-buffered''; i.e., as each packet is saved,
> it will be written to the output file, rather than being written only
>  when the output buffer fills.
> ```

After this, the script worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
until [ $x -gt 13 ];
do tcpdump -i $1 -w /home/paul/chanscan/chan-$x-$now.pcapng -e -s 0 subtype probe-req or subtype probe-resp -v & sleep 10; 
sleep 2;
```

Here is a direct kill in less code:

```
kill $(ps -e | pgrep tcpdump);
```

As you can see the instead of other variables I just killed the process 2 seconds after the 10 second sleep. The script i did contains a 10 second scan for every channel between 1-13 this was for probe requests and responses so, importance on killing the tcpdump running process was critical to start the next scan.

I always give around 2 seconds for using kill or switching channels etc. the answers above are all as equally good just thought I would show you a simplified answer that meets all needs in less code. hope this helps someone out. :-)

Answer (score -3):

You can enter the command below:

```
killall tcpdump
```

This is relevant if you had a continuous tcpdump running and wanted to end that process. Nothing else is affected.

Comment: This is relevant if you had a continuous tcpdump running and wanted to end that process. Nothing else is affected.